# Как через async\await вызвать метод DisconnectAsync у сокета?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, async-await

Как через async\await вызвать метод [DisconnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnectasync(v=vs.110).aspx) и дождаться его завершения у сокета? Этот метод не поддерживает TAP паттерн. Он поддерживает только старые асинхронные паттерны, с которыми я плохо знаком.

Comment: Есть единственный способ вызвать метод: берёте объект, вызываете метод.

Comment: @VladD, он не поддерживает TAP паттерн. Он поддерживает только старые асинхронные паттерны, с которыми я плохо знаком.

Comment: А, понял. Имеет смысл дописать это в вопрос. Я посмотрю и отпишусь позже (я с телефона).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DisconnectAsync()` действительно является старым API (EAP, event-based asynchronous pattern) и не поддерживает TAP. Однако, если ознакомиться с документаций по TAP, то можно найти [рецепт](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#Tasks%20and%20the%20Event-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20(EAP)) "преобразования" EAP API в TAP. Для этого нужно воспользоваться классом `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

```
public static Task DisconnectAsync(this Socket socket, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    // TaskCompletionSource является обобщенным,
    // поэтому используем самый "маленький" тип, действительный результат нас не интересует
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();
    // подписываемся на завершение операции
    args.Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.SocketError == null)
        {
            // если операция завершилась успешно, устанавливаем результат таску
            tcs.SetResult(0);
        }
        else
        {
            // иначе устанавливаем исключение
            tcs.SetException(new Exception(e.SocketError.ToString()));
        }
    };

    var finished = socket.DisconnectAsync(args);
    if (finished)
    {
        // операция завершилась синхронно, просто выходим
        return Task.Completed;
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Использование:

```
await socket.DisconnectAsync(args);
```

Comment: В [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8) пишут, что `SocketAsyncEventArgs` может повторно использоваться приложением, поэтому, возможно, имеет смысл отписываться от события.

Comment: @VladD да, полез читать документацию, а там какой-то ад на самом деле. События у аргумента -- это уже звоночек, но дальше идут пулы аргументов и т.д. С наскока за пару минуть раскурить не удалось :).